# How do I view the location of an swf file that is obfuscated somehow

Tags: fullscreen, sniffing, swf, obfuscate

Specifically, I'm trying to view [Elmo's Keyboard-o-rama](http://www.sesamestreet.org/game_player/-/pgpv/gameplayer/0/7d1b0f7b-1646-11dd-995c-3d52ab3e4656) fullscreen.  The [original swf file](http://www.sesameworkshop.org/uploaded-images/9495524/additional/main_game-6.swf) has been moved and obscured.  For a toddler, this game really needs to be full screen!

The toddler doesn't mind too much and has already lost interest in the game for the day.  But it's just driving me crazy.  I've tried the usual method of viewing the page info in Firefox to no avail.  And before people start trying to delete this for being game specific, I would like to know how to do this for any obfuscated swf location, not just games.  Thanks in advance.

If anybody knows how to find the appropriate information in tcpdump or wireshark, that could probably help, too.  That's what I'm trying to do right now.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be obscured, it could be protected. By looking at who's requesting the file you can write a redirect that will not allow you to actually view / download it.

Answer (score 1):

[Flash Game Maximizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9631#reviews) addon for firefox looks promising.  It still won't show me the location of main_game-6.swf that is in some sort of flash frame inside www.sesamestreet.org/DAMAsset/street/loader.swf

Answer (score 1):

There's a Windows program called [Network Miner](http://networkminer.sourceforge.net/) that allows you to sniff packets on a connection, and automatically extracts files from the HTTP data (and perhaps other protocols?). I've used it to pull images and and programs from saved Wireshark dumps, so I'm fairly sure it should be able to pull out the swf file for you.